# ROS2 through docker: failed to configure logging: Failed to create log directory

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run ROS2 with x11 support through docker, but I receive this error when I try to open rviz2:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-cocobots'
[ERROR] [1650449124.107459824] [rclcpp]: rcl context unexpectedly not shutdown during cleanup
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to configure logging: Failed to create log directory: /home/cocobots/.ros/log, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-logging-spdlog-1.1.0/src/rcl_logging_spdlog.cpp:100
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Indeed there is no log directory in /home/cocobots/.ros/log
Anyone knows what may causes the error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399311/ros2-through-docker:-failed-to-configure-logging:-failed-to-create-log-directory/) by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2022-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2022-06-15**:
It was probably an ownership problem. I had the same error, it was fixed after giving my user the ownership of his home directory.  `chown -R user /home/user`

**Comment by [Zach](https://answers.ros.org/users/108778/zach/) on 2022-06-21**:
Have there been any updates on this? I gave the user ownership of their home directory but that hasn't fixed it. The issue is also infrequent. I cannot get it to show up every time I run my ROS2 packages but it is still present about 20% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to change to the root user in order for ROS to work ( docker run ... --user=root ...).
Also, [rocker](https://github.com/osrf/rocker) by tfoote is another handy tool to tackle this

---

Originally posted by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) with karma: 233 on 2022-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0